# How to make a DataTable from DataGridView without any Datasource?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, windows-forms-designer

I want to get a DataTable from DataGridView of the Grid values.

In other words DataTable same as DataGridView Values

Comment: Can't you just instantiate a new datatable and set it as the datasource of the gridview?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Might be a nicer way to do it but otherwise it would be fairly trivial to just loop through the DGV and create the DataTable manually.

Something like this might work:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);    
}

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
```

Comment: You may want to preserve the column types in the cloned DataTable, by adding `col.CellTemplate.ValueType` argument to the `dt.Columns.Add` in line 4. (I got FormatException without this thing, when processing the copied table.)

Answer (score 13):

You can cast the DataSource object from the DataGridView to a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will not work if the DataSource is a BindingList<T>, though I was very hopeful.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following code also, this code fill not effect on your DataGridView when you do some add or delete rows in the datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = Ctype(dataGridView1.DataSource,DataTable).copy();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follow:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BLL
{
    public class Class_DataGridview_To_DataTable
    {
        public static DataTable UDF_Convert_DataGridView_To_Datatable(DataGridView ImpGrd)
        {
            DataTable ExportDataTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in ImpGrd.Columns)
            {
                ExportDataTable.Columns.Add(col.Name);
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ImpGrd.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dRow = ExportDataTable.NewRow();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                }
                ExportDataTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }

            return ExportDataTable;
        }
    }
}
```