# Export dynamically created datagridview data to xml without any SQL r database server

Tags: c#, .net

Hi can anybody help me on this issue, like i was trying to create XML file from data in datagridview. Problem is datagridview is dynamically created n it depends on the user on how many rows n columns he creates n enters the data in it. Datagridview contains columns with integer as well as string. So initializing columns n rows is bit difficult as i am a newbie. Kindly help me on this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to accepted solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109009/how-to-make-a-datatable-from-datagrid-without-any-datasource) and create a `DataTable` manually

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);    
}

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
```

After you have created this `DataTable`, create a `DataSet` and use `WriteXml`

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.WriteXml("your local path here");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)gv.DataSource;// if data source is dynamic data table it will wokr

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    string xml = ds.GetXml();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private XElement GetData(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var elem = new XElement("data");
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            elem.Add(new XElement("row",
                row.Cells
                .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Select(a => new XElement(a.OwningColumn.Name, a.Value))));
        }

        return elem;
    }
```