# How to put datagridview data into datatable? C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, crystal-reports, dataset

I have datagridview but i want to put the datagridview data to datatable which will be accessed by crystal report using dataset. the datatable is inside the dataset.

Comment: can u provide your exiting code

Comment: how the data binded in the datagridview, it is a collection of datatable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a DataTable from DataGridView without any Datasource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109009/how-to-make-a-datatable-from-datagridview-without-any-datasource)