# Converting DataSource to DataTable returns null while filtering DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview, filtering

I'm totally new to Windows Forms and especially `DataGridView` control.
The problem is when I want to filter `DataGridView` by a specific column.

In the form load event I bind data to the `DataSource` of `DataGridView` like so :

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    BindingList<Person> pList = new BindingList<Person> {
        new Person {Id = 5, FName = "James", LName = "Allan", Age = 23, Country = "United States"},
        // And so on ...
    };
    bs.DataSource = pList;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
}
```

Then here in click event of `button1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    if (dt != null)
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"FName LIKE '%{textBox1.Text}%'";
}
```

But the problem is that `dt` becomes `null` while `dataGridView1.DataSource` has value and number of records.

Comment: did you using dataGridView1.DataBind();   ?

Comment: You are binding list of person to the grid view. List can not be converted to data table that's the simple logic. That's why You are getting null.

Comment: You need to convert the DataSource of GridView to BindingList<Person> and use linq to filter.

Comment: I tried your solution dude and it worked properly. You might want to submit an answer **(in details)**. _Thank you so much_ @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: [Filter BindingSource when DataSource is a BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35562593/3110834)

Comment: Right, @RezaAghaei your opinion is the same as Chetan's comment, BTW thank you too

Answer (score 0):

A `BindingList` cannot be cast to a `DataTable`.

From [How to make a DataTable from DataGridView without any Datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109009/how-to-make-a-datatable-from-datagridview-without-any-datasource) you may check this out.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);    
    }

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataRow newrow = dt.NewRow();
        foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            newrow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(newrow);
    }
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"FName LIKE '%{textBox1.Text}%'";
}
```

Comment: I think you still might have to assign the DataTable to avoid it getting garbage collected after the method returned.

Comment: Sorry, assign with/to what?

Comment: Assign the local DataTable dt as some Property (DataSource?)  to the DataGridView

Comment: Not sure if that's what is needed that. Leaving it *OP* to decide

Answer (score 0):

```
y = x as DataTable;
```

is not a conversion of your BindingList, but is (usually) [equal to](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#the-as-operator)

```
if(x is DataTable)
    y = (DataTable)x;
else
    y = null;
```

You have to create a DataTable object by yourself, if you want to use its functionality.